# Prove that convolution in linear time invariant systems is commutative

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, convolution, signal-processing

Prove that convolution in linear time invariant systems is commutative.

I'm trying to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)h(t-\tau)d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t - \tau)h(\tau)d\tau $ but I think I may be misunderstanding something.

By change of variables for integration, I let $u=t-\tau$ and therefore with the limits of integration $u(-\infty) = t - (-\infty) = \infty$ and $u(\infty) = t - (\infty) = -\infty$.

And I get $-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t - u)h(u)du$.  But this seems like the appropriate way to change variables, am I missing something here?

Comment: If $u  = t - \tau$, then $du= -dt$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, but you forget to change the $d\tau$.
we have $$u=t-\tau$$
which implies $$du=-d\tau $$
Voila!